# grepping patterns in a json file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, json

How can I select the lines from my text files similar to this one

```
"created_at": "Wed Oct 19 12:36:54 +0000 2016"
```

basically I need to find lines with the pattern

- starts with `Wed Oct 19` and
- ends with `2016`

However, the `Wed Oct 19 12:36:54 +0000 2016` could be anywhere in the line and any other time of the day could be in between.

When I use

```
grep -irn "Wed Oct 19" | grep -irn "2016"
```

I get all sorts of unwanted results.

Here's an example of a similar line from the file I don't want to match:

```
"created_at": "Tue Jan 31 18:50:26 +0000 2012",
```

Thid is part of a tweet's attributes.

Here's a longer part of the input:

```
 "contributors": null, 
      "retweeted": false, 
      "in_reply_to_user_id_str": null, 
      "place": null, 
      "retweet_count": 4, 
      "created_at": "Sun Apr 03 23:48:36 +0000 2011", 
      "retweeted_status": {
            "text": "In preparation for the NFL lockout, I will be spending twice as much time analyzing my fantasy baseball team during company time. #PGP", 
            "truncated": false, 
            "in_reply_to_user_id": null, 
            "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
```

complete example input here:
https://gist.github.com/hrp/900964

UPDATE: I am looking for the file names that contain this pattern in them.

Comment: grep is probably not the tool you want, or at least grep will not format the output the way you want, it will print matching lines. Without a better idea of the content of the file or at least the output you want it is hard to say but you probably want a different tool such as awk or perl. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28437211/unix-print-pattern-between-the-strings

Comment: @bodhi.zazen seems to me OP wants "lines with this pattern", no?

Comment: Please give a larger sample of your input and your desired output from it if possible

Comment: @Zanna I am not sure of the input file or desired output or what is wrong with what grep is currently doing.

Comment: voting to close as the OP has not answered as to what s/he wants as output. We and all type some variants of grep, but without knowing what the OP wants for output it is meaningless.

Comment: @Zanna wrote example input

Comment: @bodhi.zazen there are lots of files among 500k files that might contain this string so I want the file names.

Comment: Now I am confused, you want only the names of the files as output ?

Comment: @MonaJalal I dont't see `2016` in your given sample!

Comment: Ok because that was just a sample. I didn't mean the input sample is the desired output! @George

Comment: Preference is to only get the name of the file yes. Currently it outputs the entire line as well as the filename

Comment: That can be fixed and you need to clearly state what you want so we can deliver!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it could be anywhere in the line, and anything could be in between, I guess

```
grep -wirn 'Wed Oct 19 .* 2016' *
```

should get it...

If you only want the filenames, use `-l`

```
grep -wirl 'Wed Oct 19 .* 2016' *
```

#### Notes

- `-w` use word boundaries in case the text you want is stuck onto something else we don't want to match (unlikely in this case)
- `-l` just print the filenames of files that contain the match
- `.*` any number of any characters here

It's probably OK to parse this file with `grep` especially for something so simple, but usinga JSON parser as mentioned in [David Foerster's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/959843/527764) is the Right Way (i.e. it will likely be more reliable, especially if you need to do anything complex).

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you guide how to use grep to select tweets between 20:30:00pm to 22:00:00pm? I am not sure if it is possible. Thanks!
"created_at": "Wed Oct 19 18:58:40 +0000 2016",

Comment: @MonaJalal assuming the times may occur anywhere in the file, I doubt `grep` can do that (but if you ask a new question about it, I maybe be proved wrong). You need some program that understands numbers, maybe `awk` or `perl`. I recommend asking a question about that :)

Comment: do you mean a json parser within bash or within Python? can you name one? There is huge number of files so I wonder if Python could be scalable at all!

Comment: I don't know how to use any @MonaJalal :( when I try I always get errors

Comment: my question might sound super weird but based on your expertise, you might have an idea. Can you please have a look? https://askubuntu.com/questions/959807/how-to-combine-the-information-in-the-line-above-in-search-for-a-pattern-in-a-li

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working on JSON data I would use an actual JSON parser:

```sh
LC_TIME=POSIX jq \
  --argjson year 2016 --argjson month 10 --argjson day 19 \
  --arg timefmt '%a %b %d %T %z %Y' \
  '.. | .created_at? | select(.) | strptime($timefmt) | select(.[0] == $year and .[1] + 1 == $month and .[2] == $day) | strftime($timefmt)' \
  twitter.json
```

- `--arg` and `--argjson` set the named variables used throughout this jq script.
- `..` returns all recursively nested objects.
- `.created_at?` returns the value of the entry with the key `created_at` if available or `null` otherwise.
- `select(.)` returns only values that are “truth-y” in ECMA Script which includes non-empty strings but not `null`.
- `strptime($timefmt)` parses a date-time string according to [`strptime(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/strptime.3posix.html) and returns a tuple of “broken down” date-time values.
- `select(.[0] == $year and .[1] + 1 == $month and .[2] == $day)` returns only values for which the given expression evaluates as true, in this case where the values of the variables `$year`, `$month`, and `$day` match their respective date-time tuple entries.
- `strftime($timefmt)` returns a date-time tuple formatted as a string according to [`strftime(3)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man3/strftime.3posix.html)

This requires jq v1.5 or later as available in Ubuntu Xenial's (or later) repositories in the [eponymous package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/jq).

Answer (score 0):

This grep should be able to fetch the wanted lines:

```
grep -E ".*Wed Oct 19.*2016$" reg.txt
```

To search files and out filename only:

```
grep -Erl ".*Wed Oct 19.*2016$" /path/to/folders/to/search
```

Comment: Ok still working on it

Comment: this seems not working. I am running it in a folder that contains folders each of which has tweets in json format.

(venv)[jalal@ivcgpu3 input_tweets]$ ls
t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8
(venv)[jalal@ivcgpu3 input_tweets]$ grep -E -r "^created_at.*\s{1,}Wed Oct 19.*2016$"
^Z
[8]+  Stopped                 grep --color=auto -E -r "^created_at.*\s{1,}Wed Oct 19.*2016$"

Comment: @Zanna the sample OP gave doesn't even contain `2016` so how does one verify the grep output?

Comment: I guess that's why in my answer I say "should get it". I created a fake sample based on OP's description (which I think I understood well enough) and file structure to test and made sure it had some nasty things in it. But the demand is so simple here I was only testing for my conscience anyway. Sometimes with text processing I want to test on something less consistent than the given sample based on description so I create a bigger sample anyway with some tricky things, so it's pretty normal

Comment: Yea @Zanna I did the same thing but apparently to me OP wasn't very clear.