# How can I include information in the line above when searching for a pattern in a line?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I need to differentiate between first image and second image scenarios when retrieveing information using grep. They both are created_at but one is for image and one is for tweet. All the ones for tweet have a `},` in the line above so I thought I could use that information however I am not sure how I could do this.

Here's the grep I use:

```
grep -wirnE 'Wed Oct 19 2(1:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|2:([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|30:00)) .* 2016' *
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mona, you've been on Ask Ubuntu for over 4 years. Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: As to the content of your question: Could you please clarify what information goes into the data filter ans/or transformer and what you expect to come out? Please use expressive examples of both.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the options `-A1` and `-B1` to let `grep` print the line after (-A) and before (-B) the matching line. Try the following command line,

```
grep -B1 created_at log-file|grep -A1 '^}'|grep created_at
```

I tested with the following input file named `log-file`

```
asdf
qwerty
...
},
"created_at" "date-with-near-}"
zxcv
some other string
"created_at" "date-without-}"
...
```

Testing sequence

```
$ grep -B1 created_at log-file
},
"created_at" "date-with-near-}"
--
some other string
"created_at" "date-without-}"

$ grep -B1 created_at log-file|grep -A1 '^}'
},
"created_at" "date-with-near-}"

$ grep -B1 created_at log-file|grep -A1 '^}'|grep created_at
"created_at" "date-with-near-}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`'s `N` command to read multiple lines into the pattern space.

To find the first one:

```
sed -nr '/\}/N; /.*\}.*\n.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016/Ip' file
```

and to remove the preceding line:

```
sed -nr '/}/N; s/.*}.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016)/\1/Ip' file
```

The problem is that `sed` won't tell you which file the line is from, and it doesn't have a recursive file search flag (afaik). That can be got around by turning on recursive globbing with `**` in the shell (but the "which file did this come from?" issue remains):

```
shopt -s globstar
sed -nrs '/}/N; s/.*}.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016)/\1/Ip' **
```

With multiple files, add the `-s` flag to make `sed` consider the stream as separate files (to avoid unwanted multi-line matches)
You can add your detailed expression in the middle...

```
sed -nrs '/}/N; s/.*}.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 2(1:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|2:([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|30:00)) .* 2016)/\1/Ip' **
```

For the second occurrence with no `}` on the preceding line

```
sed -nr '/^[^}]*$/N; /.*\n.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016/Ip' file
```

and removing the preceding line:

```
sed -nr '/^[^}]*$/N; s/.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016)/\1/Ip' file
```

#### To combine this into something more useful:

```
for f in **; do [[ -f "$f" ]] && echo -e ""$f":\n tweet: $(sed -nr '/}/N; s/.*}.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016)/\1/Ip' "$f")\n image: $(sed -nr '/^[^}]*$/N; s/.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016)/\1/Ip' "$f")"; done
```

or... slightly more readably(!)

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar

for f in **; do 
   [[ -f "$f" ]] && 
   echo -e ""$f":\n tweet: $(sed -nr '/}/N; s/.*}.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016)/\1/Ip' "$f")"
done
```

This gives output looking like:

```
file1:
 tweet: "created_at": "Wed Oct 19 12:36:54 +0000 2016"
 image: "created_at": "Wed Oct 19 somethingsomething 2016"
file2:
 tweet: "created_at": "Wed Oct 19 random-chars 2016"
 image: "created_at": "Wed Oct 19 whatever 2016"
```

If you want to exclude one or the other, remove the relevant part from the script, eg to get only the tweet...

```
for f in **; do 
   [[ -f "$f" ]] && 
   echo -e ""$f":\n tweet: $(sed -nr '/}/N; s/.*}.*\n(.*"Wed Oct 19 .* 2016)/\1/Ip' "$f")"
done
```

#### Notes

- `sed -n` be quiet until we ask for output - this is used in combination with the `p` print command to mimic the action of `grep`
- `-r` use extended regex
- `/}/N` find a line with `}` and read the next line into the pattern space
- `/^[^}]*$/N` find a line with no `}` and read the next line into the pattern space
- `I` case insensitive search
- `p` print the found/edited lines
- `s/old/new` replace `old` with `new`